# Handle cancellation of async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I'm using [Parse](http://www.parse.com) as a data store for an app, and I am implementing their [Facebook Login](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#fbusers-signup) functionality. AFAIK, this Login method isn't any different than other async methods so hopefully it applies.

So there is a Login.xaml page, that has a button for "Login with Facebook", and tapping this button takes you to the FacebookLogin.xaml page which contains only the `WebBrowser` control as per the linked Parse documenation. In `ContentPanel.Loaded` on FacebookLogin.xaml, I can use the following code to log in:

```
async void FacebookLogin()
{
   try
   {
      user = await ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(fbBrowser, new[] { "user_likes", "email" });
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
   {
      // task was cancelled, try again
      //task = null;
      //FacebookLogin();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
}
```

If I actually log in, it works, and I can navigate the user to the next page. The problem happens when I let the browser control load (so the `async` method is *waiting*), and then hit the **Back** button, **and then come back to the Facebook Login page again**.

When I do this, an `OperationCancelledException` is thrown, but I'm not sure how to handle it. What I've tried:

1. In the `catch` for the `OperationCanceledException`, set re-initialize the `WebBrowser` control to a new one. This had no effect.
2. In the same `catch`, call `FacebookLogin()` again, to retry. This also didn't work.
3. I've also tried not using `await` and returning a `Task<ParseUser>` but I wasn't sure how to go about doing that either.

Is there something I can do with the cancellation exception, or use a `CancellationToken` to handle this better? I just want to properly handle the cancellation so that I can re-load the Facebook Login page if the user presses "Back".

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, after much guidance from @JNYRanger, I have come up with a working solution. There may be a better way, but this seems to work. Here is the entire code from my FacebookLogin.xaml:

```
public partial class LoginFacebook : PhoneApplicationPage
{
   Task<ParseUser> task;
   CancellationTokenSource source;

   public LoginFacebook()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      ContentPanel.Loaded += ContentPanel_Loaded;
   }

   async void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        try {
          source = new CancellationTokenSource();
          task = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(fbBrowser, new[] { "user_likes" }, source.Token);
          await task;

          // Logged in! Move on...
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { task = null; }     
   }

   protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
   {
       if (task != null) source.Cancel(false);
       base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
   }
}
```

So basically, when "Back" is pressed, I use the `CancellationToken` to request a cancel, which throws an exception. When the exception occurs, I set `task` to null. Now, when re-navigating to the FacebookLogin page (without previously logging in), the `task` can be successfully recreated.

Comment: Careful, you still have `async void` methods that aren't event handlers.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it to work without `async void` because if `FacebookLogin()` returns a `Task<ParseUser>`, I'd have to use `await` on `FacebookLogin()`, which would require me to use `async` on `ContentPanel_Loaded`, which gives me another `async void`?

Comment: Actually, it looks like, according to the article you provided, if the `async` method is an event handler (as `ContentPanel_Loaded` would be), that is ok. So would that be a better solution to just make `ContentPanel_Loaded` `async`?

Comment: Exactly.  That would do the trick.  For non-event handlers instead of making them `async void` you can make them `async Task` where task is NOT generic.  Since you don't need `ParseUser` you don't need to use `Task<ParseUser>` Instead of returning void you are returning just a non-wrapped `Task` object that you can await just in case there are errors.

Comment: Such as `public async Task FacebookLogin()`

Comment: Thanks again. I can't update my code until I get home tonight but once I do, I'll update my solution.

Comment: Please see my updated solution. All I did was move the code from `FacebookLogin()` to `ContentPanel_Loaded` so now the `async void` method is an event handler. This also seems to work well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never have `async void` methods.  You cannot handle exceptions properly in them.  If your `async` method does not return anything use `async Task` (not generic) as the return type instead.

You can then await on your returned `Task` to handle the exceptions properly.

If you are going to set use `CancellationTokens` make your you pass your `CancellationTokenSource`'s token to the `async` method.  You can then register this token either to a callback or continue to pass the token into the `LoginAsync` method if that overload is available.  I used this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get myself familiar with the cancellation methods.

Also take a look at this article from the MSDN blog in regards to avoiding the `async void` issues: [Async-Await Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

**EDIT**
Per the edit in your question I wanted to point something out. If you call

```
Task<ParseUser> t = FacebookLogin()
```

You now have a `Task` object that you can do stuff with.  However, if you just want the `ParseUser` object and have no continuations or need to do anything else with the `Task` you should use `await` once again.

```
ParseUser p = await FacebookLogin();
```

Since this is in an event handler (loaded) it is the one exception where it's OK to have an `async void`

As to what happens when you a cancellation occurs, well that's up to you.  You can close the login window, cancel other tasks/methods, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the info, please see my update. I'm still confused as to what I need to actually *do* when a cancellation exception occurs?

Comment: It depends on what you want to happen when the method is cancelled.  What do you want to happen when the method is cancelled?
Also keep in mind that When you call `await` you are getting the wrapped value, not the task itself.

Comment: Right, I do not need the task, only the `ParseUser` so I can use it after. So, when I go to FacebookLogin.xaml the browser loads and the async method waits for the user to login. If the user doesn't log in, and taps Back instead, and then goes back to the FacebookLogin.xaml page again, the cancellation exception occurs. I don't need anything to specifically happen, I just need the task to properly be disposed of so that I can try calling `LoginAsync()` again.

Comment: That is where I am confused. I can catch the exception, but if I try calling `FacebookLogin()` again from there, I get another task cancellation exception immediately. It's like the page or *something* needs to refresh.

Comment: That might be a separate issue.  However, it might be best if you cancel the whole login and change windows at this point instead of automatically trying again.

Comment: You can then prompt the user to login again if they want and then load this window (which will load the task) once again.

Comment: Well, that is kind of what's happening. They tap 'Back' from the FacebookLogin page (without logging in), and they go back to the regular Login page. Then, if they navigate to the FacebookLogin page again, the exception occurs. So they've already changed pages, which I thought would refresh and just make another call but it seems that since the first task wasn't cancelled properly it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the code that Creates & Passes your tokens.  Remember that Tokens are ONE TIME USE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45683/discussion-between-lhan16-and-jnyranger)

Comment: I would argue that you