# C# Parse.com + Facebook Signup

Tags: c#, facebook, parse-platform, uwp

I'm having trouble implementing the user signup + login functionality in a UWP app. There isn't much information available on how to get this done in C#.NET. If I follow Parse.com's [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#users), I get a "Task canceled exception". After doing some research I found this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248000/handle-cancellation-of-async-method) which seems to resolve the exception. I'm able to get to the login page but I don't know how to redirect the user to MainPage.xaml after a successful login.

Two questions:
1- How do I detect that the login was successful?
2- Upon successful authentication by FB, how do I redirect the user to MainPage.xaml or any other page for that matter?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public sealed partial class FacebookLogin : Page
{
    Task<ParseUser> task;
    CancellationTokenSource source;

    public FacebookLogin()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        FacebookWebViewLogin.Loaded += Facebook_Login ;
    }



    async void Facebook_Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            task = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(FacebookWebViewLogin, new[] { "user_likes", "email" });
            await task;
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            task = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way of authenticating with Facebook, Microsoft have a great sample up on their blog which covers this! If you need more help with how it works, I can gladly lend a hand. - [Windows SDK for Facebook](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/14/windows-sdk-for-facebook/)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate you offering a hand with this. How do I contact you?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVcG7.png)
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.